# How to implement class structure reasonable

Tags: c#

I hope my question is legit because i'm not really used to all the hierarchical class structs.

I try to encapsulate a class that delivers the same functions for two different cameras connected to device. Those functions are thought to be within the class *DeviceObject* whilst I want to access those functions by using an instance of *Camera1* or *Camera2*. Here's some pseudo code that might not work:

```
public class Camera1 : DeviceObject
{
    public Generic.CameraSelect Camera { get; set; } = Generic.CameraSelect.CAM1;
}

public class Camera2 : DeviceObject
{
    public Generic.CameraSelect Camera { get; set; } = Generic.CameraSelect.CAM2;
}

public class DeviceObject
{ 
    public void SomeFunction() 
    {
        HardwareDriver.Function(SelectedCamera);     
    }
}
```

What I want is to easly access the methods of DeviceObject dependend on the Camera-Class:

```
public void Method() 
{
    Camera1 Cam1 = New Camera1();
    Camera2 Cam2 = New Camera2();

    Cam1.SomeFunction();
    Cam2.SomeFunction();
}
```

I apologize if this is a stupid question but after 7 hours of programming I'm completely stuck and don't get it in my head anymore :)

## UPDATE:

I have implemented - as entirely all of you have recommended - an abstract base class and derivate the Camera Objects as member of the base class.

What I didn't know so far, that it's possible to cast derived classes to the type of base classes. That was absolutely new to me but helped me a looot! with my implementation.

So thanks to all of you who helped me without minusing me to hell :)

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? I don't quite get what you are trying to achieve. Is the concept of abstract methods what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use an abstract class?

```
public class Camera1 : Camera
{
    public override Generic.CameraSelect CameraType { get; set; } = "CAM1";
}

public class Camera2 : Camera
{
    public override Generic.CameraSelect CameraType { get; set; } = "CAM2";
}

public abstract class Camera
{
    public abstract Generic.CameraSelect CameraType { get; set; }

    public void SomeFunction()
    {
        HardwareDriver.Function(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for the understandig: "this" delivers an object type of Camera1 / Camera2 - right?

Comment: It does, however, in your HardwareDriver.Function(), you'll only know that it's a Camera. 

Since the cameraType property is abstract you DO know that you can call the type on it. So you'll have a method `public static void Function(Camera camera){}`

Answer (score 1):

You typically only use inheritance when you need different *implementation* (methods).  If the implementation is the same for both cameras but the *data* involved is different, you can use one class and a factory to "create" a camera with the appropriate settings.

```
public class CameraFactory
{
    public static Camera1 {
    get {
        return new Camera {Camera = Generic.CameraSelect.CAM1};
    }

    public static Camera2 {
    get {
        return new Camera {Camera = Generic.CameraSelect.CAM2};
    }
}
```

That's not the *only* way to do it, but it is *one* way.

Also note that if the `Camera` property should not change then make it `get`-only (or at worst use a private setter.

Comment: Hi D Stanly. Thx for you reply. Even though this is not the way I'll choose this time, it will help me for another problem that's already waiting for me :)

Answer (score 1):

As other people have suggested, the answer to your question is probably to add an abstract / override:

```
public class Camera1 : Camera
{
    public override Generic.CameraSelect CameraType { get; set; } = "CAM1";
}

public class Camera2 : Camera
{
    public override Generic.CameraSelect CameraType { get; set; } = "CAM2";
}

public abstract class Camera
{
    public abstract Generic.CameraSelect CameraType { get; set; }

    public void SomeFunction()
    {
        HardwareDriver.Function(this);
    }
}
```

However, I was triggered by the `HardwareDriver` class. There are two points I'd like to make here:

1. Drivers work on capabilities, not on names. If you're goal is decomposition, you might want to go for a double dispatch that calls stuff depending on the scope.
2. What's the purpose of a camera and why is it modelled the way 'the world' works?

**Double dispatch**

Let's start with the double dispatch. The way I see it, you'll probably end up with a large 'switch' block somewhere that incorporates the logic. That doens't make a lot of sense to me. Basically you probably attempt to decouple the objects from the logic -- so let's use inheritance to do that. In this case, it'll work like this:

```
public class Camera1 : Camera
{
    public override void SomeFunction(IDeviceVisitor driver)
    {
        // Very simple camera:
        driver.HandleAngle(this, 12.0);
        driver.GenerateModel();
    }
}

public class Camera2 : Camera
{
    public override void SomeFunction(IDeviceVisitor driver)
    {
        // This camera understands focus
        driver.HandleAngle(this, 12.0);
        driver.HandleFocus(this, focus, this.focus * 1.2); 
        driver.GenerateModel();
    }   
}

public class SomeHardwareDriver : IDeviceVisitor { ... } 

public interface IDeviceVisitor
{
    void HandleFocus(Camera camera, double focusValue, double realDistance);
    void HandleAngle(Camera camera, double angle);
    void GenerateModel();
    // [...]
    // etc
}

public abstract class Camera
{
    public abstract void SomeFunction(IDeviceVisitor driver);
}
```

The reason I pass `this` along is because you might want to call another camera function from within the `HardwareDriver` to do the magic.

**Modelling in the way the world works**

If two camera have nothing with each other in common, don't give them a common base class. It makes no sense.

Or the more general rule: always remember that a class model doesn't need to make sense to you as a person; it has to make sense to a computer.

**How to know when you're running the wrong way**

2 clues:

- If you end up with large switch blocks, a lot of if-then-else's, etc -- then you're probably doing it wrong.
- If you copy-paste code, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: To answer some of your question marks: The two cameras are identical in view of the way they take a photo but are different in their installation. One device is on a x-y-plotter with a size a, the secound one with a size b. However, those cameras are connected to a server that itself can be called over a webinterface (whdl). This webinterface accepts calls in the form "WebService.TakeAPicture(Camera num)." I have to do a whole load of setting up before and also the httpbinding cannot be done twice. So I need a structure that allows me to have one setup that is commonly used by two cameras.

Comment: Sounds to me like everything I explained applies. You might even want to derive one of the cameras from the other, to inherit most of the properties.

Comment: Well, all function calls for camera1 and camera2 are exactly the same. Only the results will vary.

Comment: What I don't get in your example: Where do you use the Interface?

Comment: Sorry, that's what I get for copy-pasting stuff, stupid me.. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a encapsulating method which accepts a parameter of `DeviceObject` like

```
public void CallSomeFunction(DeviceObject dobj) 
{
    dobj.SomeFunction();     
}
```

Then you can create an instance of any of camera base type and call the method

```
Camera1 Cam1 = New Camera1();
CallSomeFunction(cam1);
```